# Find string in string by template placeholder

Tags: php, arrays, string, find

im looking for function which can find in any string part of that string which matches with my template.

For example:

```
$string = "I found this function in 2015/03/01";
$template = "XXXX/XX/XX";
$go_search = find_string_by_template($template,$string);
echo $go_search;
```

Result: 2015/03/01

Comment: Maybe `preg_match`? Actually dumb question. Here simpliest way to do it: `[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}`

Comment: ....do you mean `strpos` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple.. It can be a lot more complicated ..

```
$string = "I found this function in 2015/03/01";
preg_match("/(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})/", $string, $dates);
var_dump($dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

simple and generic solution:

```
function template_pattern($tpl)
{
   $pattern = '';
   $l = strlen($tpl);
   for($i=0; $i<$l; $i++)
   {
      $pattern .= 'D' === $tpl[$i] ? '\\d' : ('W' === $tpl[$i] ? '\\w' : preg_quote($tpl[$i],'/'));
   }
   return '/(' . $pattern . ')/';
}
```

use example:
`D` matches one digit character, `W` matches one alphanumeric character, rest characters are regex-escaped

**note** one can augment the `template_pattern` function with more options (e.g match frequent patterns, like specific date formats, file formats and so on, but it is good for a start)

```
preg_match(template_pattern("DDDD/DD/DD"), "I found this function in 2015/03/01", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015/03/01
    [1] => 2015/03/01
)
```

if you want to match and capture the whole string and extract the template as a group you can do a variation:

```
function template_pattern2($tpl)
{
   $pattern = '';
   $l = strlen($tpl);
   for($i=0; $i<$l; $i++)
   {
      $pattern .= 'D' === $tpl[$i] ? '\\d' : ('W' === $tpl[$i] ? '\\w' : preg_quote($tpl[$i],'/'));
   }
   return '/.*?(' . $pattern . ').*?/';
}


preg_match(template_pattern2("DDDD/DD/DD"), "I found this function in 2015/03/01", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => I found this function in 2015/03/01
    [1] => 2015/03/01
)
```